# Infinite Limits at Infinity (1)

Tags: calculus

Prove that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3x^3-4x+1}{2x^2+2}=\infty.
\end{equation} I am having trouble proving this question. You must use the limit definition for infinity. That is, given any $N>0$ , there exist an $M>0$ such that if $x>M$ then $f(x)>N$. Note this is not evaluating limits it is a formal proof.

Comment: Actually do the division.  $\frac{3x^3-4x+1}{2x^2+2} = \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{1-7x}{2x^2+2}$.

Comment: I did that already using algebraic long division. But how do I prove this limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{3x^3-4x+1}{2x^2+2}= \frac{3}{2}x+\frac{-7x+1}{2x^2+2}\equiv f(x)+g(x).
\end{equation*}

Now use the definition of the limit that you have and show that given $N>0$ there exists an $M_1$ and an $M_2$ such that $f(x)>2N$ for $x>M_1$ and that $|g(x)|<N$ for $x>M_2$. So by setting $M\equiv\max\{M_1, M_2\}$ you will have both are true and hence for $x>M$ you will have

\begin{equation}
f(x)+g(x)>N
\end{equation}

Comment: I'm a bit lost with what you said. So how would you start of the proof in your case

Comment: Given $N>0$, set $M_1>4N/3$ then for $x>M_1$ we have\begin{equation} f(x)=\frac{3}{2}x>\frac{3}{2}\frac{4N}{3}=2N.\end{equation} Now find show that for some $M_2$ if $x>M_2$ then $|g(x)|<N$. Consequently, you will have for $M\equiv\max\{M_1, M_2\}$ and $x>M$,\begin{equation}f(x)+g(x)>2N-N=N.\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to show $\lim_{x->\infty} \frac{3}{2}x = \infty$.  So we need to show the other term is bounded.

Suppose $x>0$, so $2x^2+2>0$, and we want
\begin{align*}
     &-1 < \frac{1-7x}{2x^2+2} < 1 \\
\iff &-2x^2 - 2 < 1-7x < 2x^2+2  \\
\iff & 0 < 2x^2-7x+3 \wedge 0 < 2x^2+7x+1 \\
\iff & 0 < 2x^2-7x+3 
\end{align*}
 which is true for all $x>3$.

Now, let $M \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $M>\frac{7}{2}$.  Let $x>\max(3,\frac{2}{3}M+\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{2}{3}M+\frac{2}{3}$.  Then we want $\frac{3x^3-4x+1}{2x^2+2}>M$.  \begin{align*}
\frac{3x^3-4x+1}{2x^2+2} &= \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{1-7x}{2x^2+2} \\
    &> \frac{3}{2}x -\left| \frac{1-7x}{2x^2+2} \right| \\
    &> \frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}M+\frac{2}{3}\right)-1 \\
    &\quad = M
\end{align*} and we're done.

Comment:  We only use the lower bound on $M$ to drop the $\max$ for $x$.  If we argue instead about "sufficiently large $M$", then both are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. By chance you know were I can get resources to further understand limit proofs. Because not getting any resources

Comment: @CRB: This is more of a practice-practice-practice thing.  The outline is always the same:  Do some exploratory scratch work, then write down which inequalities worked.  Much of the practice is about recognizing which expressions are ultimately bounded, what sorts of expressions to use in the inequality bounds, and how to piece together inequalities from different parts of the givens.  Sketching the graphs can help.  You can start building this knowledge by *reading* lots of limit proofs.  There are literally hundreds of (advanced) calculus textbooks in libraries with many such proofs each.